# Why was my answer deleted?

Tags: support

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801149/point-renderings-slightly-off-in-mathematica) yesterday, but my answer was deleted. Why is that?

The contents of the answer were:

> I have a problem that looks very much like the "juddering" described in this topic. My program loads a file containing a few hundred 3D points into a list. The points are arranged in a spiral and dispersed by bounded randomization. I rotate the spiral around the z axis and create a table of graphics objects using
>
> Table[Graphics[Rotate[Point[pointlist]]]]
>
> with appropriate parameters and options. The output is Export[]'ed to an animated .gif file.
>
> I was surprised to see the z axis wandering around near the origin. The points appear to remain in correct locations with respect to the axes. I tried adjusting PlotRange as an option of Graphics[] in various ways to no effect.
>
> This program is a variation on another program that had stable axes but generated the points internally, so I am puzzled by the difference in performance. I will be studying the remarks in this topic closely, but meanwhile if someone has a quick fix or just an explanation, it would be welcome.
>
> I would attach the file "wandering_spiral.gif" and any other part of the program that might be of interest, but .gif is not supported as an upload and I have yet to master the skill of creating .mov files.

Comment: `Welcome to Stack Overflow! This section is for answers. If you have a question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button.`  At SO, not here.

Comment: As @Uphill says - because it was not an answer, simple as that.

Comment: @user see if [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165754/mathematica-3d-plots-prevent-notebook-jitter-while-rotating-3d-image-with-mouse) can help you through.

Comment: One of the reasons why SO is such a powerhouse is because we keep a tight ship ("we" meaning our regular user base and moderators (diamond and 10k+ rep users).  Don't take it too personally.  Just about everybody here has had something similar happen to them early on.  Read the faq, lurk a little bit (here and on [main]) if you want to stick around.

Answer (score 22):

Your "answer" is not an answer, it's another question. The moderator who deleted your answer commented on it first, so you should've gotten a message in your inbox about it:

> Welcome to Stack Overflow! This section is for answers. If you have a question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. – Bill the Lizard♦ 20 hours ago